# Efficient Sorted List Python

Tags: python, data-structures, time-complexity

I am looking for a Python datastructure that functions as a sorted list that has the following asymptotics:

- `O(1)` pop from beginning (pop smallest element)
- `O(1)` pop from end (pop largest element)
- `>= O(log n)` insert

Does such a datastructure with an efficient implementation exist? If so, is there a library that implements it in Python?

Comment: Python can almost do this with a regular list, using `bsearch`, but insertion will take O(n) unfortunately. A deque may not support efficient lookup to allow meaningful binary search.

Comment: `heapq` provides the first and last items, but only goes one way.

Comment: You maybe need [sortedcontainers](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/)

Answer (score 1):

A regular red/black tree or B-tree can do this in an amortized sense. If you store pointers to the smallest and biggest elements of the tree, then the cost of deleting those elements is amortized O(1), meaning that any series of d deletions will take time O(d), though individual deletions may take longer than this. The cost of insertions are O(log n), which is as good as possible because otherwise you could sort n items in less than O(n log n) time with your data structure.

As for libraries that implement this - that I’m not sure of.

Comment: Maybe https://pypi.org/project/bintrees/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. How would you maintain those pointers after the smallest or largest element gets deleted? Would that not be a log(n) process?

Comment: @student1868 You can thread a doubly-linked list through the nodes to navigate from each node to the one before or after it. Also, I think (?) the cost of moving from the leftmost/rightmost nodes in a red/black tree to the ones before/after them takes time O(1).

Comment: @templatetypedef nothing special - just any "Red/Black Tree" time complexity. But I've found some.. Thanks.